# Sacar expresion regular de Multiples coincidencias

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Estoy trabajando en una limpieza de BD para unificar dos tablas distintas y tengo unos 2000 mil registros con el problema que intento explicar a continuación.

Tabla A

```
NK INTER ZAPRESIC              
NK RUDES                       
SSV JAHN REGENSBURG   
1. FC MAGDEBURG       
Adelaide United FC
```

Tabla B

```
INTER ZAPRESIC        
RUDES                
JAHN REGENSBURG       
FC MAGDEBURG          
ADELAIDE UNITED
```

Y así muchísimos ejemplos mas unos 2000, la cuestión seria poder unificar esas dos tablas en una ya que cada una tiene un ID diferente y necesito hacer alguna expresión regular o algo para realizar la búsqueda de las dos coincidencias entre si para saber sus ids que son diferentes en cada tabla a la hora de unificarla, no se si existirá alguna expresión regular que pudiera hacer lo que pretendo para realizar la búsqueda a ver si me podéis ayudar o se os ocurre alguna forma mas de intentar hacer algún tipo de coincidencia para sacarlos, muchas gracias un Saludo

Answer (score 0):

Mira esta idea

Tienes dos Tablas ( a , b )

```
SELECT * FROM a
 OUTER JOIN b ON (  
   (  a.campo like '%' || b.campo || '%' ) 
      or 
      b.campo like '%' || a.campo || '%' ) 
   )
```

Con esto likeas[1] a ambas columnas, a mi me ha funcionado antes.

- O sea, likear, yo likeo, tu likeas, el like... es una broma gramática.